# How do I catch a packet sniffer in local area network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security

Actually I am a college student and in our hostel someone is regularly attempting attacks like ARP poisoning which leads to great loss of bandwidth.Please briefly explain the techniques which you recommend.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. How do you detect the bandwidth loss today? What have you tried? How did you figure out that it is ARP poisoning? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If they're ARP Poisoning, then they have a MAC address you can track down. If the hostel uses a manageable switch and they'll let you have admin access to it, you can see which switch port that MAC address was on at the time of the attack and track it down that way. If it's a wireless device you can use Wireshark in 802.11 monitor mode and walk around with your laptop looking for the spot where transmissions from that MAC address are strongest.

If you can run a sniffer on a mirror port of the switch, you may be to see traffic that originates from that machine itself (as opposed to stuff it's relaying from other machines during attacks), and possibly determine its IP address(es), and then scan for services (port scans) on those addresses, or look for name protocol announcements from those addresses, or maybe even use something like nmap OS fingerprinting on those addresses, to try to gather more information that may provide further clues.